# How can I choose between select.select() and select.poll() methods in the select module in Python?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, select, network-programming

I am writing an application in Python that involves socket programming. I have understood that it's better to use the non-blocking sockets, and thus write an event-driven server. I am not sure as to why and how I should prefer one of these two methods that I want to use: select() and poll() for checking activity in any of the sockets. Could anyone help me out if there's anything in either of these methods that makes it a better choice that the other?

I mean, why would I choose one over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do. Usually I would use select over poll but it depends.
First, select and poll work with blocking sockets and let you multiplex a thread I/O among all sockets.

Second, if you want to use non-blocking sockets you don't need to use select or poll, you just read (recv) or write (send) and it could return without having done anything. In C, if it would block, the operation will return an error telling you it would block (if it were a blocking socket).

Regarding the difference between select and poll, both allow you to multiplex IO and let you handle multiple sockets with only one thread. But poll let's you work with any STREAMS device.

Additionally, according to documentation
http://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html#poll-objects

poll scales better, I don't agree because both select and poll have the same time complexity, but documentation says so. The thing is that poll uses a list of file descriptors and select uses a bitmap that goes from 0 up to the highest file descriptor you want to check. poll let's you manage higher number of events like high priority data. For me, poll is more complex to handle than select because in select you can clearly separate sockets ready to write from sockets ready to read and those with error.

Also you can take a look at C versions which do almost the same:
http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman2/poll.2.html

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `select` with a timeout of 0 is basically the same as a poll but the biggest problem for cross system programming is that the support for both `select` and `poll` is mixed and inconsistent - personally I tend to opt for a blocking listener in a separate thread that once a complete frame, message, etc., has been received raises an event with the data attached - this seems to work well cross systems.

Comment: Thank you Steve. Actually, my biggest concern is not cross-system inconsistencies, at least right now. My issue lies in how I should choose poll() over select() or vice-versa...